# Only allow certain ports to be accessible from one subdomain

Tags: nginx

I have multiple domains and subdomains, and I have a serivce on a port, that I'd like to setup so that it's accessible only on one certain subdomain. So for example `foo.bar:9999` works, but `bar:9999`, `baz:9999`, and `foo.baz:9999` doesn't.

How do I achieve it? I'm not able to find anything. I'm using nginx if there is a way to do it via it.

Comment: I think this is your answer: https://serverfault.com/a/690242/505063

Comment: Thanks a lot! This looks like it should solve my problem.